# accessing shape events in vsto

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I added a shape to my spreadsheet this way :

```
MOC.MsoAutoShapeType DefaultShape = MOC.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape CurBlock = Activesheet.Shapes.AddShape(DefaultShape, Left , Top, Width, Height);
```

However I can't figure out how to access any of the shape's events

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which shape events are you looking for, specifically? Excel exposes few events out of the box, but it is possible to create your own events by processing the shapes when selections change etc (see this article for an example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't see any events out of the box. I just want some basic ones, like click, move etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is none. The link @Gedde provided explains how to build custom events.
In a nutshell, you must respond to the 'private void commandBars_OnUpdate()' which is the only event that gets fired when you do anything on the spreadsheet.